# Angular dart on WebStorm. Debug is no more working

Tags: dart, angular-dart

It is a week now that I have problems debugging angular dart applications in WebStorm. If I use debug on a console (server) application everything works fine.
I tried to roll back to angular 4.0.0 (on dart 1.24.3), but this didn't help.
I really don't know what kind of info could be useful. 
Please, let me know if there is some configuration file that I can print or that could be important in order to fix the problem. I tested a lot of configurations, but, at present, I'm not able to work properly. After filling up my code with print statements, there are some cases where also this practice is not enough.

Edit1:
   I have tried to create a sample project. With no DDc and target chrome, the debugger stops but not on all breakpoints. With no DDc and target Dartium, it does not stop.

Edit 2:
  I was running my application with target dartium, because with target chrome I had an annoying error that I was not able to catch. Now I got it, and running the project with target chrome, revives the debugger. This is a good new. Just a question, is a problem of release 1.24.3 (Dartium has not been released for this release) or something else? Anyway, if this is a known problem, it wouldn't be better to disable the target dartium on WebStorm when the release is 1.24.3?

Edit 3:
  Now the debugger is working, but only on the project you are developing. The imported packages are not stopping on breakpoints. As my project is divided in a lot of packages, I cannot debug approximately 80% of my code.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What you are hitting here isn't functionality directly in an Angular Dart or Dart issue, but in the JS Debugger in WebStorm.

Open an issue on YouTrack here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Include not only the version of Angular and the Dart SDK, but also the version of WebStorm, and an example of where breakpoints are not working.

Finally, there is some information in this issue that might help: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30593

Comment: Thanks. It seems it is related also to issue  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29809