# Debug of Angular Dart stopped working in PhpStorm

Tags: dart, phpstorm, webstorm, angular-dart

I have quite big Angular Dart project in PhpStorm. I was able to debug it, but suddenly it doesn't work anymore (for few weeks). I'm not sure what's the reason as I upgraded PhpStorm, Dart Plugin and Dart. But I expect debug to be working with all updates.
I created the simpliest Angular Dart app (ToDo example) to see if it helps. It didn't.

```
Dart VM version: 2.3.1 (Tue May 21 19:28:38 2019 +0200) on "linux_x64"

PhpStorm 2019.1.2
Build #PS-191.7141.52, built on May 8, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 5.0.17-300.fc30.x86_64

PhpStorm Dart plugin v191.7221

Google Chrome Version 74.0.3729.169 (Official build) (64bit)
```

Dart is listening on port 53322 for HTTP connections from browser, PhpStorm is listening on debug port 63344 (and has a connection from Chrome), Chrome is listening on debug port 45389 (and has a connection from PhpStorm).

When I open `http://localhost:53322/index.html` I see the app, but the execution is not stopped on breakpoints.

I've found similar bugs (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30593, [Angular dart on WebStorm. Debug is no more working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48627170/angular-dart-on-webstorm-debug-is-no-more-working)) but the provided solutions didn't help.

Is there a way to make debug working again? I'd like to avoid downgrading.

Comment: *"Dart SDK 2.3.1"* -- another recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56313763/dart-2-3-ignores-breakpoints ---> please check & follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-39095

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not specific to Angular - debugging web apps doesn't work with SDK 2.3.1. Please follow [WEB-39095](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-39095) for updates.

Workarounds:

- Start debug session from WebStorm. Breakpoints won't work. Stop Debug
  session.
- Without closing the project go to Terminal and run `pub global activate webdev 1.0.1`.
- Start debug session from WebStorm again. Breakpoints should work.

Or:

- Run webdev server manually from Terminal explicitly specifying hostname, for example: `pub global run webdev serve --hostname 127.0.0.1 web:53322`
- In the IDE create **JavaScript Debug** run configuration that opens webdev URL directly, e.g. `http://localhost:53322/index.html`, press **Debug**

**Update**: it was a bug in webdev (no sourcemaps on ipv4). Bug is fixed in webdev 2.0.7. No actions needed, WebStorm will auto-update webdev automatically to the latest version

Comment: Thank you. I've run these commands in terminal
```> pub global deactivate webdev #maybe not needed

> pub global activate webdev 2.0.5 # 2.0.5 is last working version

> pub global run webdev serve --hostname 127.0.0.1 web:53322```
and then run Debug session from PhpStorm.